# services.yml and path to file in same bundle

Tags: symfony

How do i refer to a data file in the services.yml, which is located in the same or any bundle?

Im shipping a csv-file which i would like to inject as argument.
It works when i use the direct path:

```
mybundle.data.csv: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/mybundle/my-bundle/mybundle/MyBundle/Resources/data/data.csv
```

This is pretty verbose and unflexible and thus i am looking for a resolver like:

```
data.csv: "@MyBundle/Resources/data/data.csv"
```

But this is not working:

> ... has a dependency on a non-existent service
>   "mybundle/resources/data/data.csv".

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: in the YAML service and parameter definitions @ also refers to another service. That is why your code does not work.

Basically you have two possibilities. The first and simple one is to use a relative path in your bundles `services.yml` and append it in your CSV class.

For example:

```
# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    data.csv: "Resources/data/data.csv"
```

In the class you want to read the CSV file:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Import/ReadCsv.php
...
class ReadCsv
{
    ...
    public function __construct($csvFile)
    {
       $this->csvFile = __DIR__.'/../'.$csvFile; 
    }
    ...
}
```

The other possibility is to make the filename of the CSV file configurable via `config.yml` (see [this article in the Symfony2 cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)) and insert a special placeholder in the config value that you replace in your `AcmeDemoBundleExtension` class:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeDemoBundleExtension.php
...
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    ...
    $container->setParameter('acme_demo.csv_file', str_replace('__BUNDLE_DIR__', __DIR__'./.., $config['csv_file']);
}
...
```

Your `config.yml` would look like:

```
# app/config/config.yml
acme_demo:
    csv_file: __BUNDLE_DIR__/Resources/data/data.csv
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. so its not really possible. from your proposals i like the extension solution best, thou it adds some kind of custom convention with the placeholder. when extending a bundle you would also have to take care of the Extension code, right? so i rather stick to the absolute path since its a plain,clear convention.

Answer (score 4):

@-escaping in yaml is supported now

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4889

You can use it like this

```
data.csv: "@@MyBundle/Resources/data/data.csv"
```